Access firestore collection in firebase cloud functions
How to get access to firestore collection:
Here my code:
const {onSchedule} = require("firebase-functions/v2/scheduler");
const {getMessaging} = require("firebase-admin/messaging");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const tools = require("firebase-tools");

initializeApp();

....

exports.myFunction = onSchedule("* * * * *",
async (event) => {
  const tokensRef = getFirestore().collection("myCollection");
  const tokens = await tokensRef.get();

  if (tokens.isEmpty) {
    logger.log("There are no tokens to send notifications to.");
    return;
  }
  logger.log(`There are ${tokens.length} tokens` +
  " to send notifications to.");

  const messages = [];
  notificationTokens.forEach((child) => {
    logger.log(`token ${child.token} `);
    messages.push({
      data: {
        "fcmToken": child.token,
      },
      token: child.token,
    });
  });

....

On the cloud functions logs Explorer I get this error:

Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required

and my own logs look as follows: token undefined and There are undefined tokens to send notifications to.
I have basically used one sample code from the cloud functions tutorial as inspiration, but they use realtime database instead.
token in child.token is a field from the collection.

How do you know the error is on one of the lines you're showing here, and not one of the lines you're not showing (I suspect there is a lot in .... that could be problematic)?  Please do some debugging to narrow this down to the specific line of code.

I managed to fix it.
exports.myFunction = onSchedule("* * * * *",
async (event) => {
  const tokensRef = getFirestore().collection("myCollection");
  const tokens = await tokensRef.get();

  if (tokens.empty) {
    logger.log("There are no tokens to send notifications to.");
    return;
  }

  const messages = [];
  notificationTokens.forEach((child) => {
    messages.push({
      data: {
        "fcmToken": doc.data().token,
      },
      token: doc.data().token,
    });
  });
    logger.log(`There are ${messages.length} tokens` +
      " to send notifications to.");
      const batchResponse = await messaging.sendEach(messages);

